# How can I test if a Perl string contains a non-negative number?

Tags: perl

I need to detect whether a value input by a user contains a positive, non-zero number.  The input field represents a product quantity, and must be greater than zero, and contain no alpha or non-numeric characters. IOW, the input must contains only these characters: 0123456789   But of course, zero by itself is not acceptable.  Here's how I am using the code:

```
  if( $fields{'quantity'} =~ [this is where I am unsure]  )
  {
    $errors .= "Please enter a whole number for the quantity.";
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to match a positive integer of arbitrary precision, you can use a simple regex: `/\A [1-9][0-9]* \z/x`, it will only match Western Arabic numerals regardless of wheter of not the given input contains other numeral systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that strings like `1E4` are also numeric, so not every number has to contain `[0-9]` only.

The `looks_like_number` function provided by [`Scalar::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar%3a%3aUtil) is the Right Way to check if a variable is numeric.

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

if ( not looks_like_number( $fields{quantity} ) or $fields{quantity} <= 0 ) {

    warn "Please enter a whole number for the quantity";
}
```

The same thing more succinctly:

```
warn "Please enter a whole number for the quantity"
  unless looks_like_number( $fields{quantity} )
         && $fields{quantity} > 0;
```

Be warned that strings like `Nan`, `Inf` and `Infinity` are also [deemed numeric](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html), so you may want to consider weeding those out as well:

```
warn "Please enter a whole number for the quantity"
  unless looks_like_number( $fields{quantity} )
         && $fields{quantity} !~ /Inf|NaN/i
         && $fields{quantity} > 0;
```

Comment: LOL, typed exactly the same answer at exactly the same moment :) BTW, `looks_like_number` doesn't accept only decimals, [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html) states: > Test if the content of an SV looks like a number (or is a number). Inf and Infinity are treated as numbers (so will not issue a non-numeric warning), even if your atof() doesn't grok them. Get-magic is ignored.

Comment: @creaktive: Yup, looks like you and I were thinking the same thing at the same time (again) :)

Comment: As well as the `Nan`, `Inf` etc. nonsense, the code needs to check that the input isa *whole* number, so it seems that `looks_like_number` is far from being the best solution after all!

Comment: If you use `looks_like_number()` for validation of external data, you might end up with more than you bargained for! <https://metacpan.org/module/String::Numeric#COMPARISON>

Comment: @chansen : Seeing that you're the module author, why don't you post a [`String::Numeric`](https://metacpan.org/module/String::Numeric) answer for future visitors?

Answer (score 3):

There really is no need to allow for exotics like `1E4` in the input: just make them type a string of digits.

Also, checking for the truth of the value entered will weed out `undef`, zero, and the empty string, so this will work fine. It checks that the input is defined, non-empty, non-zero, and contains no non-numeric characters.

```
unless ($fields{quantity} and $fields{quantity} !~ /\D/) {
  $errors .= "Please enter a whole number for the quantity.";
}
```

Comment: Would not reject `"00"` or `"\x{0669}"`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is safer to use the `looks_like_number` from [Scalar::Util](http://cpan.me/Scalar%3a%3aUtil) as the answer by @Zaid pointed out, but here's a regexp version:

```
if (not defined $fields{'quantity'}) or $fields{'quantity'} !~ /^[0-9]+$/ or $fields{'quantity'} <= 0) {
    $errors .= "Please enter a whole number for the quantity.";
}
```

Comment: Fails to reject `"00"` or `"\x{0669}"`.